# Linearly independent vector set in $\mathbb R^4$ and linearly independent set of polynomials in $\mathcal P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I wanted to share just a little bit more creative and different task than others from one exam,  with my idea and see if there are better ideas than mine (I  believe there always are).

For an arbitrary vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb R^4$ let's define a real polynomial $\sigma (x)\in \mathcal P_3$ with a variable $t$ in the following way:
$$\sigma (x)=x_1+(x_1+x_2)t+(x_1+x_2+x_3)t^2+(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)t^3$$

Prove that: if $\{x,y,z\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb R^4$, then $\{\sigma(x),\sigma(y),\sigma(z)\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathcal P(3).$

An interesting fact is:
$$\dim\mathbb R^4=\dim\mathcal P_3$$
Linear independence of vectors $x,y,z$ $\in \mathbb R^4,\;\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in \mathbb R$

$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4),z=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$

$\;\;I=\alpha{x_1}+\beta{y_1}+\gamma{z_1}=0$

$\;II=\alpha{x_2}+\beta{y_2}+\gamma{z_2}=0$

$III=\alpha{x_3}+\beta{y_3}+\gamma{z_3}=0$

$IV=\alpha{x_4}+\beta{y_4}+\gamma{z_4}=0$

In order to get a null polynomial:
$\alpha\sigma(x)+\beta\sigma(x)+\gamma\sigma(x)=0$ all the coefficients here have to be  zero:

$\alpha{x_1}+\beta{y_1}+\gamma{z_1}=0=I$

$\alpha(x_1+x_2)+\beta(y_1+y_2)+\gamma(z_1+z_2)=0=I+II$

$\alpha(x_1+x_2+x_3)+\beta(y_1+y_2+y_3)+\gamma(z_1+z_2+z_3)=0=I+II+III$

$\alpha(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)+\beta(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4)+\gamma(z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4)=0=I+II+III+IV$

If the first system of equations implies scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in \mathbb R$ are all equal to zero, then it is also the case in $\mathcal P_3$ and polynomials $\sigma(x),\sigma(y),\sigma(z)$ are lineraly independent and so is the set $\{\sigma(x),\sigma(y),\sigma(z)\}\subset\mathbb R^4$

Comment: Your are almost at the end... What can you conclude from the last 4 equations?

Comment: @FakemistakeThank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^4 \to P_3$ is linear, $\dim \mathbb{R}^4 = \dim P_3 = 4$, and $\ker \sigma = \{0\}$, hence $\sigma$ is invertible.

Suppose $\sum_k \alpha_k \sigma(x_k) = 0$ then $\sigma_k (\sum_k \alpha_k x_k) = 0$
and so $\sum_k \alpha_k x_k = 0$.